# from cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

The gradient is known as $\nabla u=(u_x,u_y)$ .

Let $x=r\cos(\phi),\ y=r\sin(\phi)$.
Does it then become $(u_r,\frac{1}{r}u_\phi)$?
I have given that $u(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))=r^3\cos(\phi)$. From this I have to calculate the gradient.

Comment: Do you mean in the basis $(\hat{r}, \hat{\phi})$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function in (non-spherical) polar coordinates i.e. $f(r, \phi)$, then the gradient is given as

$$\nabla f(r, \phi) =\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{r} + \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\hat{\phi}$$

Comment: thank you , this I know , but my problem is that u depends on $(rcos(\phi),rsin(\phi))$

Comment: Your function $u$ can be expressed as being dependent on $r$ and $\phi$ as $u(r,\phi ) = r^3 \cos (\phi)$ and you would just take the partial derivatives as the definition of $\nabla$ implies.

$$\nabla u(r, \phi ) = 3r^2\cos (\phi ) \hat{r} - r^2 \sin (\phi ) \hat{\phi }$$

$x=r\cos (\phi )$ and $y=r\sin (\phi )$ are simply the transformations required to go from Cartesian to polar.

Comment: Well , you mean defining $u(rcos(\phi,rsin(\phi)):=v(r,\phi)=r^3cos(\phi) $ $\nabla v = (3r^2cos(\phi),-r^3sin(\phi))$

Comment: $r^2$ on the second term, but yes this is what I mean. Usually, the transformation will take $u(x,y)$ to $u(r,\phi)$, not so literally as to $u(r\cos(\phi), r\sin(\phi))$.

Comment: I do not really know , where you got the basis (\^{o} r ,\^{o} \phi)

Comment: @GolD.Roger I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Something is wrong with your typesetting.

Comment: srry , I just wanted to ask why you got the basis $\hat r and \hat \phi$

Comment: The basis $(\hat{r},\hat{\phi})$ is standard for a polar coordinate system.